# How to read data out of angular Resource promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem reading my data out of angular promise returned.

previously i did

```
var data = category.get({id:userid});
```

Then i realised data returned an unresolved promised . Then changed it to

```
category.get({id:userid}, function(result){
     console.log('the result are', result);
 });
```

When i print my result, i noticed its now a resolved promise with my data inside Resource : 0 like below.

[image]

Please how to i access the Resource below ? It does not seem to allow access. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to actually use the `promise` you can do:

```
category.get(...)
  .$promise.then(function(result)) { 
    console.log(result); 
  });
```

Otherwise, you're not using a promise.