# How to update variable with nested functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a sample code

```
function() {
    var test = 0;
    var url = 'http://test.php';
    var user_id = 1;
    $http.post(url,{user_id: user_id})
    .then(function (response){ 
         test = response.something;
    })
    console.log(test)
}
```

It returns the value 0. I need it to return response.something.

Comment: You have to wait the promise to be resolved. See a similar situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259349/how-to-access-a-returned-result-outside-the-then-in-javascript-angularjs/

Answer (score 2):

You're not invoking the function calling `test = 1`

You can wrap the inner function within an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
function() {
    var test = 0;
    (function(){
        test = 1;
    })() // Call the expression immediately
    console.log(test)
}
```

#### Edit for Question Update

The `console.log(test)` is happening before the promise from `$http.post()` resolves, you need to move the `console.log()` within your `then()` callback.

```
function() {
    var test = 0;
    var url = 'http://test.php';
    var user_id = 1;
    $http.post(url,{user_id: user_id})
    .then(function (response){ 
         test = response.something;
         console.log(test) // Move console.log inside promise then
    })

}
```

Comment: this does not work for me. i am updating my test inside this `$http.post(url,{user_id: loggedin_id})
 .then(function (response){ 
  this.test = 2;
})`

Comment: i have edited the sample code for better understanding.

Comment: That totally changes the question because you're trying to log before the promise has returned

Comment: @TheChosenOne see updated answer

Comment: but i need to access test outside of $http.post(). How do i do that?

Comment: You could return it or take it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$http.post` is an asynchronous method call. By the time your code gets to the `console.log` call at runtime, the data from `$http.post` may not have returned yet, therefore it would log the old value and not the new one.

If you want to `console.log` the value after the post request has returned, you should move the `console.log` statement to the `then` block which will only run after the call has been returned.

```
function() {
    var test = 0;
    var url = 'http://test.php';
    var user_id = 1;
    $http.post(url,{user_id: user_id})
    .then(function (response){ 
         test = response.something;
         console.log(test) // Move console.log inside promise then
    })

}
```

If that does not work for you, it is because your call is likely failing for some reason or another. In this case, you can provide an additional function to handle the error.

```
function() {
    var test = 0;
    var url = 'http://test.php';
    var user_id = 1;
    $http.post(url,{user_id: user_id})
    .then(function (response){ 
         test = response.something;
         console.log(test) // Move console.log inside promise then
    }, function(err) {
       test = err;
       console.log(test)
    });
   }
```